# Constructing a joint distribution from marginals with a particular form of dependence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f_X (x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ be the density functions for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that both have support $[0,1]$. I would like to construct a joint density function $f(x,y)$ for the random vector $(X,Y)$ with the property that $f(x,y)=0$ for all $x<y$. I do not otherwise care about the correlation structure, and I do not care about uniqueness. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Let $U_1, U_2$ be i.i.d. $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$. Take $X = \max\{U_1, U_2\}, Y = \min\{U_1, U_2\}$.